# Timer android java to count

Tags: android, timer, count

I am developing an android app, which uses the Timer. I want to create a timer that count example to 3 min, after that I want to create function or using  true to check if the time go to 3 min or not like  :
`if (time < 3 min ){do something }`
thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Timer timer = new Timer(); //init the timer
Handler handler = new Handler();
int counter = 0; //counter to indicate the total second whenever timer fire

timerTask task = new timerTask();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,500,1000); //(which task to run,forget the usage try google, looping must be milisecond eg.1000 = 1 second)



private class timerTask extends TimerTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                counter++;
                if(counter >= 90){ //check wether it is 90 second (1 and half minutes)
                    //do something
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)) might help you ... You can also use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to do a job after intervals ...